# How do I mimic images swiping within an iPad frame?

Tags: css, swiper.js

We have a series of slides. Each slide contains an image. We want to have a static iPad frame on each slide and have slide transitions make it appear as if the images are swiping within that frame only.

I'm using [Swiper](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/) to mimic the touch slider effect.

I've created a codepen illustrating what we're after [here](http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/dXoGgd?editors=1000).

The basic HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/302/?random" />
      <p>Harry Potter is a series of fantasy literature written by British author J. K. Rowling. The novels chronicle the life of a young wizard, Harry Potter, and his friends Hermione Granger and Ron Weasley, all of whom are students at Hogwarts School
        of Witchcraft and Wizardry.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/301/?random" />
      <p>Jason Bourne is a fictional character and the protagonist of a series of novels by Robert Ludlum and subsequent film adaptations. He first appeared in the novel The Bourne Identity (1980), which was adapted for television in 1988.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/304/?random" />
      <p>Chiang Mai (/ˈtʃjɑːŋˈmaɪ/, from Thai: เชียงใหม่ [tɕʰiəŋ màj] ( listen), Lanna: ᨩ᩠ᨿᨦᩉ᩠ᨾᩲ᩵ [t͡ɕīaŋ.màj] ( listen)) sometimes written as "Chiengmai" or "Chiangmai", is the largest and most culturally significant city in Northern Thailand.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
```

Maybe there is a best way to do this within Swiper, and maybe it's just a clever CSS solution? I'm not sure.

Ideas? Suggestions? Solutions? :)

Answer (score 0):

So I finally worked out a solution.

If instead of 1 slider, I use 2 and sync them. I can constrain the size of the 1 slider to be exact size I need for the iPad.

My forked codepen solution [here](http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/oLXodX?editors=0010).

```
<div class="ipad-slider">
  <div class="swiper-container image-slider">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/400/?random" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/420/?random" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/410/?random" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <img class="ipad-frame" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14057353/ipad_isolated-cropped.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-container quote-slider">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Harry Potter is a series of fantasy literature written by British author J. K. Rowling. The novels chronicle the life of a young wizard, Harry Potter, and his friends Hermione Granger and Ron Weasley, all of whom are students at Hogwarts School
          of Witchcraft and Wizardry.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Jason Bourne is a fictional character and the protagonist of a series of novels by Robert Ludlum and subsequent film adaptations. He first appeared in the novel The Bourne Identity (1980), which was adapted for television in 1988.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <p>Chiang Mai (/ˈtʃjɑːŋˈmaɪ/, from Thai: เชียงใหม่ [tɕʰiəŋ màj] ( listen), Lanna: ᨩ᩠ᨿᨦᩉ᩠ᨾᩲ᩵ [t͡ɕīaŋ.màj] ( listen)) sometimes written as "Chiengmai" or "Chiangmai", is the largest and most culturally significant city in Northern Thailand.</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
<hr />
```

Making sure I sync the sliders with the following JS..

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var quoteSwiper = new Swiper('.quote-slider');

    var imageSwiper = new Swiper('.image-slider', {
      nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
      control: quoteSwiper
    });

  });
```